# How to execute selenium NUnit test cases from jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, nunit, selenium-grid

I have installed Jenkins and want to execute selenium test cases from Jenkins.

I have installed selenium grid plugin for Jenkins and running a server as node.
My scripts are written in c#.

For Java, I think it can be done using ant or maven XML.

But don't know how to execute NUnit test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project under configuration

1. Click "add another task"
   and add "Run unit tests with MS Tests".
2. You need to specify where your test lies. (I would use a .dll of a specific test project).
3. Just hit run and it will execute.

Also make sure that you have specified following tags in your code

```
[TestClass] //On your class
[TestMethod] //On each method
```

Comment: Hi Sascha, thanks for the reply. I have already done that for code coverage using nunit but those were unit test cases, i want to know how to execute selenium test cases so that i can see them running on browser. And one more thing my test cases are BDD tests.

Comment: I'm not sure if i get what you're saying. If you start the test via TestExplorer in Visual Studio you should be able to see them running inside the browser. Same goes for starting it on Jenkins. A browser will open on the same workstation.

Comment: Hi Phylax that is my problem when i am running the selenium test cases from jenkins, browser is not opening. i can see the console output and it seems good. However i have integrated selenium grid in jenkins but not sure where i have to use it ?

Comment: I do not have experience with that. I'm afraid i cant help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

I never bothered installing any additional plugins for Jenkins as NUnit tests can be executed via console, as you would locally.

You could just execute a windows batch command in Jenkins:

`nunit3-console.exe --test=namespace.class.method test.dll`

Prerequisites:

- NUnit console runner installed on the node (nunit3 in this case). (Official installer: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/releases)
- Add folder location of installed console runner to system PATH variable. (For example C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console)

Remember that you need to re-connect your node to Jenkins Master in order for the updated system variables to be picked up.

So, your final batch command could look something like:

`nunit3-console.exe --test=AutomatedTests.FrontEndTests AutomatedTests.dll`

This would execute all of the tests from the FrontEndTests.cs, of your built AutomatedTests.dll

(There's a bunch you can do via console, check out: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line)